# How to set the index of a pandas DataFrame to match the index of a datetime series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame of a datetime series and a pandas DataFrame with a numbered index:

​How do I set the index of the DataFrame with the numbered index to match the index of the DataFrame with the datetime series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If same length of both `DataFrames`:

```
df1.index = df2.index
```

Or:

```
df1= df1.set_index(df2.index)
```

Comment: thanks man I knew it was going to be something ridiculously easy. I knew I was going to get downvoted for this one just go tired of looking in docs. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @lopezdp - I think you was donwvoted not for question, but for post pictures. [Reason why not post images of code, data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @lopezdp - Yes, next your question should be better, I believe. Btw, here is nice posts about [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) ;)

Comment: it's weird. on the first run your answer worked. Now I am rerunning and I am getting this error: pred.index = ax.index

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'index' any ideas?

Comment: @lopezdp - Sure, I think problem is `ax`, is is name of DataFrame or of `axessublot`? Maybe try rename dataframe to `df` from `ax` ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
df.index = pd.PeriodIndex(df.Date, freq='D')
```